# css: different column container height in Chrome & Safari (bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have such code (it's a prototype, in real app everything is different, but the same schema):

```
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 d-none d-sm-block">
        <div class="h-100" style="background:red">
          123123
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 d-none d-sm-block">
        asdasdasd <br> asdasdasd <br> asdasdasd
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/TyrOGOCNBHePtbxH6xYN?p=preview

I'm using bootstrap 4.

But in Chrome everything is fine:
[image]

not in Safari (v10.1): [image]

what i do wrong? is it possible to change this style, without rebuilding my DOM?
so height should be the same as in Chrome

Comment: I don't have Safari, so can't test it myself, so I wonder if this work before posting an answer: https://plnkr.co/edit/MlIfOIl6OKyPgtm9lTbQ?p=preview

Comment: @LGSon no no no. Please do not change -block to -flex

Comment: First, did it work? ... Second, explain why you need block.

Comment: @LGSon thank you. But not in one my case. See comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the given code, this won't work on Safari.

The reason is quite simple, as when you set `h-100` (`height: 100% !important`) on the inner `div`, that percent value will be based on the parent's set height, which in this case has none, hence the computed value will be `auto`.

The other browsers appear to use the computed height of the `col-3` flex item element and its parent's `align-items: stretch`, hence there it work.

This sample proves that, as if you set `align-items` to `flex-start`, it will fail in the other browsers too: https://plnkr.co/edit/LqSqK4j4GhpDbkc4E0i5?p=preview

---

A better approach is to make use of Bootstrap 4 and the Flexbox model properly, which in this case, for flex row items, has its `align-items`. Its default value is `stretch` and does exactly the same thing as `height: 100%`.

And since there isn't anything you can do with a block element that you can't with a flex element, simply change `h-100` to `w-100` and `d-sm-block` to `d-sm-flex` and it will work.

[Updated plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Qqrof95vlEft51vGELsm?p=preview)

Stack snippet

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 d-none d-sm-flex">
        <div class="w-100" style="background:red">
          123123
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 d-none d-sm-flex">
        asdasdasd <br> asdasdasd <br> asdasdasd
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

A better approach than using `w-100` (`width: 100%`) would be to use `flex: 1`. Since Bootstrap's `col` rule does that, but also has padding, you could create one of your own, here called `flex-1`.

```
.flex-1 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 0;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ODeYcUgEDdZjysnCQSYB?p=preview

---

Or use `col` combinded with a new rule that removes the padding, here called `nopadding`

```
.nopadding {
  padding: 0;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/jj07PrEVXDMW2eRLw4Ti?p=preview

Comment: no, this won't work at least in one case, i'm gonna show you code, exactly what I mean

Comment: @brabertaser19 That would be great.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/gQdLjTVH2N70AFOYfqiJ?p=preview for example - this won't work in Safari (but in Chrome - it's ok)

Comment: @brabertaser19 How does this work in Safari https://plnkr.co/edit/BgO2ENwlQgATzOi40TPf?p=preview ... and if you check some of my notes in the CSS, you'll see that you use some properties wrong, which is the primary reason it wont work cross browser. And unfortunately some of this stuff still work in Chrome, which it shouldn't.

Comment: @brabertaser19 Here is a version that also work in IE ...and should in Safari too https://plnkr.co/edit/Qg872PA3Iz2rbK0YclRK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Same issues fixed with following :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't do anything wrong, Bootstrap simply uses vendor prefixes for its columns that aren't covered in Safari.

The default Bootstrap properties for columns are:

```
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-webkit-flex: 0 0 25%;
-ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
flex: 0 0 25%;
```

I don't have Safari, so can't verify this, but you **should** simply have to add:

```
.col-3 {
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
```

Safari 10.1.1 onwards [**supports flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), so this will force Safari to render the column in a flexbox layout, thus resolving the height issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Safari support non prefixed Flexbox since ver. 9

Comment: Also, to add `display: -webkit-flex` will make no difference since the already set `d-sm-block` use `!important` ... and btw, I didn't down vote :)